# Basic Android - Purpose of MainActivity

Tags: java, android

Just started developing with Android.

Do we want the MainActivity to contain any sort of user interface? Ex. Should it present the user with a login option or whatever? Or should MainActivity just have instructions to be executed at the apps launch, and then redirect to another java file that will present the user with the first thing s/he sees?

If it is the latter, how can I make MainActivity redirect to another java file once everything is executed upon the apps launch? As in automatically, without the click of a button or anything.

Thanks and sorry but I am new to this

EDIT:
Is there anything like the iOS app delegate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should it present the user with a login option or whatever?

The primary role of `Activity` is to present the user with a user interface. Whether that is "a login option or whatever" is up to you.

> Or should MainActivity just have instructions to be executed at the apps launch, and then redirect to another java file that will present the user with the first thing s/he sees?

That is not a common pattern.

> how can I make MainActivity redirect to another java file once everything is executed upon the apps launch?

Call `startActivity()` to start up another activity, then call `finish()` to get rid of the activity that you are in.

Comment: is there anything like the iOS app delegate then?

Comment: @user3794585: Since I do not do native iOS development, I cannot answer that.

Comment: so research tells me that there should be an application file then, that would have any initializing commands such as referencing a ParseSDK? as in your class would be "... extends Application" instead of "... extends Activity". Where is this file? Or do we make it ourselves?

Comment: @user3794585: "so research tells me that there should be an application file" -- that is a possibility. Whether it is appropriate for the Parse SDK is something you should ask the people at Parse. "Where is this file? Or do we make it ourselves?" -- you make it yourself.